# Problem with Intel UHD Graphics 630 on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: graphics, 22.04, intel

Just installed 22.04.3 on a (new to me) Lenovo m720q w/Intel UHD 630 graphics.  Having major video issues - it will boot up and sometimes let me login, but shortly after that it will freeze, start display odd artifacts on the screen, etc.

I was able to boot into recovery and get it to use safe-mode graphics and then it works without issues.

I am running a pretty high resolution (3840x1600), not sure if that is an issue?

Looking for suggestions - I'm fairly new to Ubuntu unfortunately (but have 30+ years of IT experience so not afraid to experiment!).

I did get Ubuntu installed on my laptop with Intel UHD 620 graphics and haven't had any issues.

Is there a different release I should be trying?  Something with updated drivers?

Comment: Some discussion of various fixes here, not sure if any worked. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2483059